# Rules not working as expected - tags don't fire

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up tracking on Google Tag Manager today and am having some trouble with rules.

I have a custom HTML tag where I'd like to fire only on a given page:

https://example.com/index.php/page/index/10

Call the rule "Page 10". In rules I have tried:

url equals: https://example.com/index.php/page/index/10

url contains: page/index/10

url ends: page/index/10

url contains: page/index/10

When this rule is applied to the tag in question it does not fire. I know the tag works because when I apply another rule to it, all pages (url regex .*) it works fine. But, this tag must only work on page 10.

Is anything apparent from the info given? I'm not sure what else could be relevant?

Comment: Don't forget, you need to create a version and publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing immediately jumps out. Are you sure you're viewing the secure version of the URL when testing?

Comment: I'm viewing with an updated and published container so yes it's secure version

Comment: Nothing is getting appended, neither? Try {{url}} matches RegEx (ignore case) `https:\/\/example\.com\/index\.php\/page\/index\/10`

Comment: Still no success. I also tried {{url}} matches regex page\/index\/10. What do you mean by appended and ignore case? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: There are two options for matching RegEx: one that ignores case and the other does not. My understanding is that {{url}} matches the entire url, not just the path. If you wanted to try just matching the path, GTM has a macro called url path. By appended, I mean is there a query string or anything appended to the url. For example, [https://example.com/index.php/page/index/10&uid=2]

Comment: That did it! Changed to {{url path}} contains page10. I never realized that {{url}} had to match the entire url (And even so, I tried the entire url with no success.

Comment: Rad! It's strange that the full URL isn't working. My guess is that it has to do with the proxy. Anyways, best if luck!